# UIScrollview setContentOffset with non linear animation?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiscrollview

I am trying to reproduce the smooth animation of a scrollview with paging enabled when you actually scroll to the next page. It seems to be `UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut`, but I need to have a "next page" button and trig the scroll programmatically.

Here is my code :

```
-(void) scrollToPage:(int)page
{
    UIScrollView *scrollView = contentView;
    CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(scrollView.bounds.size.width * page, scrollView.contentOffset.y);
    [scrollView setContentOffset:offset animated: YES];     
    [self pageControlUpdate];
}

-(void) scrollToNextPage 
{
    [self scrollToPage:(pageControl.currentPage + 1)];
}
```

I cannot manage to reproduce the smoothness of `UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut`, 
either with `setContentOffset`, or with `scrollRectToVisible`... 
it goes to the next page with an ugly linear animation

I even tried to animate it manually :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    scrollView.contentOffset = offset;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {    } ];
```

where am I wrong ?

Comment: I found this : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ScrollingViewContent/ScrollingViewContent.html which confirm what I saw : `The setContentOffset:animated: method scrolls the content to the specified content offset. If the animated parameter is YES, the scrolling will animate from the current position to the specified position at a constant rate.`

Comment: arg. Noone could have any clue ?

Comment: Well, if `UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut` doesn't work it's probably a different animation curve. It's very possible Apple uses a custom curve for this animation. Using `CAPropertyAnimation`, you can define your own custom curve in the form of a `CAMediaTimingFunction`. It might be worth playing around with different control points.

Comment: I can't manage to make it work. 
Would you know a tutorial or a code sample to use  CAPropertyAnimation ?

Answer (score 21):

Every time you make your own animations you have to pass **NO** as `animated:` parameter:

```
- (void)scrollToPage:(int)page
{
    UIScrollView *scrollView = contentView;
    CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(scrollView.bounds.size.width * page, 
                                 scrollView.contentOffset.y);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         [scrollView setContentOffset:offset animated:NO];
                     } completion:nil];

    [self pageControlUpdate];
}
```

Comment: and btw. a fix animation time will look odd in some cases. e.g. you only scroll 2 lines it will also take a half second. And the other direction if you have a really, really long list and you scroll from top to bottom it will be super fast in half a second.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation but I only scroll by a full page width so it always seems the same speed. 
I tried with the animated:NO parameter but it keeps scrolling at fixed rate. I also tried to change the UIViewAnimationCurve animations but it look the same. 
I am trying the custom CAPropertyAnimation solution of Ole.

Comment: This works great. Small nitpick though, it should be UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut.

Comment: great answer, best on here!

Answer (score 6):

With the use of public APIs, I don't believe this is currently possible. Assuming you don't need user interaction during the course of the animation, you'd be better off animating the position of your `UIScrollView`'s subviews (ie. the scroll view's content) instead, and then adjusting the `contentOffset` without animation on completion. You could do it like so:

```
- (void) scrollToPage:(int)page {
    UIScrollView *scrollView = contentView;
    scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(scrollView.bounds.size.width * page, scrollView.contentOffset.y);
    CGFloat delta = offset.x - scrollView.contentOffset.x;

    __block int animationCount = 0;
    for (UIView *view in scrollView.subviews) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            animationCount++;
            CGRect frame = view.frame;
            frame.origin.x -= delta;
            view.frame = frame;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            animationCount--;
            if (animationCount == 0) {
                scrollView.contentOffset = offset;
                for (UIView *view in scrollView.subviews) {
                    CGRect frame = view.frame;
                    frame.origin.x += delta;
                    view.frame = frame;
                }
                scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

I can confirm this works as expected, I tested it myself.

Comment: Yes, it's an interesting alternative solution. But I do need to use the realtime contentOffset value to move my view inside the scrollview while scrolling, and this solution does not trig scrollviewdidscroll.

Comment: Well it does trigger `scrollViewDidScroll` when you set the `contentOffset` at the end. But you could just extract whatever extra handling you perform in `scrollViewDidScroll` and instead use it within this method.

Comment: Alternatively, you could embed all of your `UIScrollView` subviews in another `UIView`, which you could subclass and override `setFrame:`, since during an animation it would be essentially equivalent to `scrollViewDidScroll`.

Answer (score 4):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:(Animation_Duration)
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                     [scroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(PointX, PointY) animated:NO];
                      }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){}];`
```

Answer (score 3):

This class absolutely saved my life:

[MOScroll on GitHub.com](https://github.com/plancalculus/MOScrollView)

It has

`- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset
      withTimingFunction:(CAMediaTimingFunction *)timingFunction
                duration:(CFTimeInterval)duration;`

Just like the private API but with all public methods and math.