# iOS TableView with paging?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am working on an iOS app with a nice UI for viewing users’ friends which is currently in a vertical ScrollView with paging enabled and 100×100pt pictures. However, with 500+ friends, this is insanely inefficient and slow, loading all of those pictures in memory at once. What I’d like to do is use a TableView and load the images when I load the cells, but I really like the snapping effect of having a ScrollView with paging enabled.

How would you recommend I add this functionality to a TableView?

Comment: @bhavyakothari, please do not use `code formatting` as emphasis.  Generally, please do not add emphasis at all in your suggested edits.  Also, there is no need to use HTML for newlines.  You should [review the formatting guide](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting the `pagingEnabled` property of your UITableView to YES is always an option… However, default UIScrollView paging will automatically page in multiples of your UITableView's frame height (unlikely the same height of your UITableViewCells), so you'll probably need to implement `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset.` This method is called when a UIScrollView (or UITableView) begins to decelerate, and it allows us to specify where the UIScrollView should finish movement.

```
-(void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
                    withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity 
             targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint*)targetContentOffset
{
    //Intercept and recalculate the desired content offset
    CGPoint targetOffset = [self recalculateUsingTargetContentOffset:targetContentOffset];

    //Reset the targetContentOffset with your recalculated value
    targetContentOffset->y = targetOffset.y;
}
```

You may want to check out this post ([UITableView w/ paging & momentum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284392/uitableview-w-paging-momentum)) in order to get a feel for how you'll need to tailor the target content offset recalculation method to fit your needs.

Comment: can anyone translate it in swift?

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` inherits from `UIScrollView` so table views have the `pagingEnabled` property just like scroll views do. Just send `-setPagingEnabled:YES` to your table view just like you would with your scroll view.

For example, in a `UITableViewController` subclass implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.pagingEnabled = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't like the scrolling when the UITableView's Paging was enabled so I wrote these two TouchUpInside methods (in C# for Xamarin) and left Paging on the table view disabled.  I added buttons that the user can tap to go to the next or previous page.  When paging down, the next item that is found is scrolled to the top of the table view's frame.  When paging up, the algorithm adds one row to the found item to try to show an item that is not straddling the table view's frame.  No checks are done for very tall cells that might be larger than the table view's bounds.

```
partial void buttonNextPageClick( NSObject sender )
{
  NSIndexPath path;
  CGPoint scrollpoint;

  scrollpoint = new CGPoint( 5f, tableviewFOO.ContentOffset.Y + tableviewFOO.Bounds.Height );  // down a page

  path = tableviewFOO.IndexPathForRowAtPoint( scrollpoint );
  if ( path == null )
    path = NSIndexPath.FromRowSection( tableviewFOO.NumberOfRowsInSection( 0 ) - 1, 0 );

  if ( path != null )
    tableviewFOO.ScrollToRow( path, UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, true );
}

partial void buttonPreviousPageClick( NSObject sender )
{
  NSIndexPath path;
  CGPoint scrollpoint;

  scrollpoint = new CGPoint( 5f, tableviewFOO.ContentOffset.Y - tableviewFOO.Bounds.Height );  // up a page

  path = tableviewFOO.IndexPathForRowAtPoint( scrollpoint );
  if ( path == null )
    path = NSIndexPath.FromRowSection( 0, 0 );
  else
    path = NSIndexPath.FromRowSection( path.Row + 1, 0 );  // +1 for the cell that might be completely visible

  if ( path != null )
    tableviewFOO.ScrollToRow( path, UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, true );
}
```